# `pod setup` consuming a significant amount of disk space

Tags: ios, cocoapods, diskspace

I just discovered today that the master Specs repo for Cocoapods was taking up 27GB of disk space in my ~/.cocoapods directory. After doing some research it appears this happened as part of the upgrade to v1 and is likely the cause for the long-running commands referenced here:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4989

And then the rationale for switching from a shallow to a full copy is outlined by the team here:

http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/

Understandable reasoning, especially in terms of the CPU utilization problem.

The disk space required, though, is just too much (10% of my 256GB drive) - especially when considering that some of that precious space on my laptop is being used for `xuchenOnlyTestDemo`, `xuchenOnlyTestDemoTwo`, `xuchenOnlyTestDemoThree`, and `xuchenOnlyTestDemoFive`. Not terrible offenders specifically, but more an indication of the problem that there are a ton of Specs being pulled that I don't anticipate using.

I'm re-running `pod setup` after having removed the master repo locally to see if I had something wacky in my local setup, but it appears not:

```
pod setup --verbose

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `<CocoaPods Specs repo>` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone <CocoaPods Specs repo> master
  Cloning into 'master'...
  Checking out files:  22% (22726/100426)
```

(I had to substitute `<CocoaPods Specs repo>` in the output above because SO wouldn't let me include more than 2 urls.)

Setup is back to 5GB used and climbing. I am presently using an SD card as an extended storage option and have my `~/.cocoapods` symlinked over to a directory on that mounted drive (OSX El Capitan). So that helps, but isn't ideal.

Are others experiencing the same issue? Anyone have a workaround to having the full master repo cloned locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to run `pod repo update` and the job again ran for 8+ hours and now consumed 38GB of disk space on the linked SD card.

I managed to free up enough space on my internal disk to experiment with removing the symlinked ~/.cocoapods directory and that resulted in much more acceptable behavior. Without the symlink, the disk usage drops drastically to:

```
$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ du -d 1 -h
420M    ./.git
538M    ./Specs
959M    .
```

This is on MacOS Sierra (10.12.2). Hope this helps someone facing a similar situation.

Comment: how did you remove the symlinked?

Comment: It's been a while, but iirc I used `unlink` to kill the symlink.

Comment: @Sean22 where did you run `unlink`? My `~/.cocopods` folder is taking 1.6 gb!

914M ./Specs
624M ./.git
1.5G .

Comment: Having trouble recalling the specifics, but I believe the issue was that I had created a symlink from my home `~/.cocoapods` to a different mounted volume (an SD card plugged directly into my old MacBook pro). I unlinked `~/.cocoapods` so that the pods would instead all be stored to the internal disk and the behavior described stopped. Hope this helps!